# How do I return the number of elements in an array using for of loop javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

How do I return the number of elements in an array using for of loop javascript?

I know how I can use a `for` `loop` to do this but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a `for of` loop. In this case would using a regular `for` `loop` be better and or the only way to do this is with a loop?

Regular for loop that prints the number of elements in the array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function logElementForLoop(arr) {
  console.log("For Loop");
  let elemInArr = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    elemInArr = i + 1;
  }
  console.log(elemInArr);
}

logElementForLoop(arr);
```

Comment: do you want to count the elements?

Comment: Why not use ``arr.length`` to get the number of elements in the array?

Comment: Yes I want to count the elements with a for of loop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a for of loop...*

Yes, it is possible, simply increment the variable (*elemInArr*) inside the loop:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function logElementForLoop(arr) {
  console.log("For Loop");
  let elemInArr = 0;
  for (let i of arr) {
    elemInArr++;
  }
  console.log(elemInArr);
}

logElementForLoop(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like `for of` or `for in` loops

```
let count = 0
for(const item of array) {
  count ++
}
console.log('array contains', count, 'elements')
```

or

```
let count = 0
for(const index in array) {
  count ++
}
console.log('array contains', count, 'elements')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `1` to the count, instead of assigning the index plus one.

```js
function logElementForLoop(arr) {
    console.log("For Loop");
    let elemInArr = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // add one for each element
        // elemInArr = elemInArr + 1;  // is doing it the long way
        // elemInArr += 1;             // jsut add one, handy for adding different values than one
        elemInArr++;                   // standard approach
    }
    console.log(elemInArr);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

logElementForLoop(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need to count array elements in for loop..? then

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Counter var
let counter = 0;

// Count in for loop
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) counter++;

// Log
console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a for of loop

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function logElementForLoop(arr) {
  console.log("For Loop");
  let elemInArr = 0;
  for (let i of arr ) {

    elemInArr = arr.indexOf(i) + 1;
  }
  console.log(elemInArr);
}

logElementForLoop(arr);
```

or simply increment `elemInArr`

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    function logElementForLoop(arr) {
      console.log("For Loop");
      let elemInArr = 0;
      for (let i of arr ) {

        elemInArr++
      }
      console.log(elemInArr);
    }
logElementForLoop(arr)
```